# FTP access instead of SFTP

Tags: ftp, sftp

We want to provide access to upload files on a FTP server.
How to provide the access for the same?

What is difference between a FTP and SFTP server?

Comment: We can't tell you how to set up a FTP server.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, both do the same thing, but SFTP sets up an encrypted tunnel first. This is important because without it, the username and password people use to log in can be read by anyone who can see the traffic.

SFTP is recommended if you care about the files staying private.

Comment: Nitpicking: SFTP is not a tunnel for FTP, and you can't use SFTP to protect your FTP server ;-)

Comment: @AviD I'm trying to read my sentence the way you did, and I'm having trouble. So, I'm not sure how to change it.

Comment: Don't bother, like I said I was just nitpicking ;-) My point was that SFTP and FTP are completely different and unconnected, if you're using SFTP you don't even *have* and FTP server :P